# How to use whose to ask who did what?

Tags: grammar

I would like to know how to properly construct a sentence with the following idea:

- There's a completed project, and I wanna ask who came up with the project (using the word **idea**)

Do I ask like this? Does below sound correct and is grammatically correct?

**... And whose idea was to build this project again?**

Comment: Not quite. You have to have a noun phrase balancing _whose idea_ on the other side of _was_, so you need to add _it_: _And whose idea was **it** to build this project again?_

Comment: Are you asking again or building it again?

Comment: @Jim asking again.

Comment: @JohnLawler that's it. Thanks. Awsome!